# Change generic nullability type in a generic type definition (in ! or ?, out always !)

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have the following extension method:

```cs
public static IRuleBuilder<TModel, TProperty> NotNull<TModel, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderInitial<TModel, TProperty> ruleBuilder)
```

where `TProperty` could be anything, but in this case I'm interested in a reference type. Let's says it's an `IEnumerable<string>`.

I would like to redefine the method above so it can accept as `TProperty` both `IEnumerable<string>` and `IEnumerable<string>?`, but the type in the returned interface would always be `IEnumerable<string>`.

It is possible? Any hack to do something similar would work. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to use a `TProperty?` type argument in the parameter type, and a `TProperty` type argument in the return type. See [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDZICYgNQA+AxAHYCuGGEwGcABHCdbQLABQ7AAgEwCMXABjqdeAFgDc7dgEkAShTgAhMpmyJpJNDDQQMAHgD2wAFZwAxjCTDeAZj0iBAPgD8jumk3bddALx1ylACEkmxyCsqqiIYm5pbWdg6ObiRwAB4wvu6eOhgAdAByBjD5FBgAFACUIVw21gBswtx0AMJ0AN7sdF3CtSINYbQRGGoIegAqALIGalh0YwAKCAYADogwAJ5uhcWl41MzVgtLqwgbjmWd3VcwABZoUHQDSirD6tm6e9Nws0cra+uuOgIcIvEYVS5dDpsK7XG5LADu/jgiO20jAy1oYEY8GwAFFUmY4MttAYSJUQlcAL7sakcNicWoeeAIABmEEJj3kg1Bby0OU+Bzmiz+p027ChtJqWWZbI5TyGIwF30OwpOZ3FNKAA).

```cs
#nullable enable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

IRuleBuilderInitial<object, IEnumerable<string>?> initial = null!;
IRuleBuilder<object, IEnumerable<string>> next = initial.NotNull();

public static class C {
    public static IRuleBuilder<TModel, TProperty> NotNull<TModel, TProperty>(
        this IRuleBuilderInitial<TModel, TProperty?> ruleBuilder)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IRuleBuilderInitial<TModel, TProperty>
{
}

public interface IRuleBuilder<TModel, TProperty>
{
}
```

Note that there are limits around fully generalizing over nullable reference types and nullable value types. The above sample would do what you expect for a reference type, but if you wanted to do something similar for value types, I think you'd need to split into two overloads, where one has constraint `where TProperty : class` and the other has constraint `where TProperty : struct`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but that has one problem: If initial IS NOT nullable (so TProperty is IEnumerable<string>), that would't work. And it is not possible to have an overload of the exact same type but without the nullable argument.

Comment: If `TProperty` is only used in outputs in the interface, you could try changing the IRuleBuilderInitial declaration to `out TProperty`.